# dotnetopenauth - How to add extra data in the refresh token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm currently working on a project where an iPad application requires access to an existing web application. The iPad application has been developed internally and is therefore a trusted application. However the data provided by the web application is sensitive so we don't want to store client credentials on the iPad. We also want the ability to revoke iPad access without affecting regular user access.

Given the above, the OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Credentials grant/flow was a good fit for our requirements which we've implemented with DotNetOpenAuth since its an established library.

However, we now require some metadata to be added to the access and refresh tokens for the resource server. The authorization server is adding the metadata via the AuthorizationServerAccessToken.ExtraData property in our implementation of the IAuthorizationServerHost.CreateAccessToken method:

```
public AccessTokenResult CreateAccessToken(IAccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequestMessage)
{
    var accessToken = new AuthorizationServerAccessToken();

    // Add some extra data to access token
    accessToken.ExtraData.Add("server_parameter1", this.ServerValue1);
    accessToken.ExtraData.Add("server_parameter2", this.ServerValue2);

    // Set ResourceServerEncryptionKey properties etc

    return new AccessTokenResult(accessToken);
}
```

This does exactly what we want for the access token however the same "ExtraData" is not included in the refresh token which causes an issue when the access token expires and needs to be refreshed because we effectively lose the additional data (since the old access token is discarded).

Can anyone advise if its possible to populate the refresh tokens "ExtraData" in the current version of DotNetOpenAuth in a similar way to the access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think there is currently a way to embed extra data into the refresh token.  Let's talk a bit about why this is.

First off, there is no such thing as a trusted iPad app, whether you develop it or not.  The problem is that apps you distribute (even internally) can't keep a secret.  Any client_secret, certificate, etc., can be cracked.  Therefore apps you distribute can't authenticate themselves to the server.  If the server can't authenticate the client, the server can't trust the client.

Now let's look at your scenario a bit more (and if you have more feedback, it may be best to continue the discussion on dotnetopenid@googlegroups.com).  The client has data that it wants to eventually end up at the resource server.  You're currently trying to pass that data through the authorization server first, then via the access token to the resource server.  Why is that?  Why not just have the client send the data directly to the resource server along with the access token?  If the answer is that the resource server shouldn't trust the client, then what you have by sending it by way of the access token is a false sense of security for the reasons given in the above paragraph. If the client could provide false info to the resource server, it could also provide false data to the authorization server.

One valid use of extra data in the access token is data that the authorization server knows for itself -- not data that came from the client.  In which case, it can look up that data each time an access token is minted and doesn't therefore have to be stored in the refresh token.

Comment: Sorry my question was misleading - the extra data actually comes from the authorization server and is required by the resource server when a client is making requests. The client is unaware of the extra data. I've edited the question to clarify. However judging by your first comment it appears it isn't possible anyway. Please let me know if this is the case and I'll mark this as the excepted answer

Comment: Is it possible to determine the username in the CreateAccessToken method? I've reviewed our code and we could avoid the extra data in the refresh token if we could determine the user when creating an access token.

Comment: Right. It's not possible. It's great to hear that all you need is access to the authorizing user. This was merely an oversight that `CreateAccessToken` left that parameter out. It will [be fixed soon](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/219).